# In iOS how to handle EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY errors?

Tags: ios, swift, out-of-memory

In my app I have an image resizing method that I use to create a thumbnail of an image; here is the code.

```
    private func resize(withSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 1)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        draw(in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
```

When resizing big images (can be a 7Mb PNG that uncompressed became 200Mb...) the `draw(in:)` crash with following error: `EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY`.

*This is not an exception that can be catched with a try-catch block.*

How can I handle a controlled shutdown instead of a crash?